# When I specify a range of y, the graph is not displayed correctly in that range

Tags: python, plotly

When I specify a range of y, the graph is not displayed correctly in that range.
I want to display the y-axis in the range of `10f~5u` on the log scale, but it doesn't display properly. How can I solve this problem?

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[10 ** -15, 5 * 10 ** -6])
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_type="linear",
    yaxis_type="log",
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the values specified as `layout_yaxis_range` are interpreted as logarithms (note that log(1.000011) is 5e-6)

Comment: I know that 1.000011=5e-6, but it is obviously confusing, so I want to use notation like u,n,p,f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for log plots](https://plotly.com/python/log-plot/), it says that

> Setting the range of a logarithmic axis with plotly.graph_objects is very different than setting the range of linear axes: the range is set using the exponent rather than the actual value:

So for your example, you can remove the `10 **` when setting the range, and your range can look like `[-15, 1.000011]`

The output with this change produces a graph that looks like this:

[image]

For reference, the complete code looks like:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-15, 1.000011])
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_type="linear",
    yaxis_type="log",
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I want it to start at 5u, how do I do that?

Comment: Try changing the `layout_yaxis_range` to `[-14, -5.5]`, it doesn't explicitly show 5u on the axis, but I believe that it is showing 5u as the top value

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for your help.